Getting zip from s3 into Lambda Function construct
I am fairly new to working with AWS CDK, and having scoured the internet for help, I figured I might be better off picking the brains of experts in the field.
I am using S3 deploy to bundle my lambda code as a zip to a specified s3 bucket. My plan is to use the zip for a lambda deployment later. All goes well until it's time for my lambda function to reference the object of the zip. I get error message: "Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey. S3 Error Message: The specified key does not exist."
I have tried moving the s3 bucket creation as well as s3 deploy to a different stack (s3 stack), and export the output from both to see exactly what is being referenced and then import them into the lambda stack. Looking at the output from the s3 stack, both the bucket and hash of the zipped file were printed to the console but I keep getting the same error on lambda stack. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!
Edit: Not sure why the image I added isn't showing up. Below is my code
export class LambdaStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

     // Define the S3 bucket for deployment
     const deploymentBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'DeploymentBucket', {
      bucketName: 'test-deployment-bucket-100',
      versioned: true,
    });

    // Deploy the Lambda function code to the S3 bucket
    const deployment = new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'DeployLambdaCode', {
      sources: [s3deploy.Source.asset(path.join(__dirname, '../lambda/test'))],
      destinationBucket: deploymentBucket,
      //destinationKeyPrefix: '',
      extract: false,
    });

    // Define the Lambda function
    const lambdaFunction = new lambda.Function(this, 'LambdaFunction', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
      //pick up lambda code from the S3 bucket
      code: lambda.Code.fromBucket(deployment.deployedBucket, cdk.Fn.select(0, deployment.objectKeys)),
      handler: 'index.handler',
    });

    // Add dependency to wait for the S3 deployment to complete
    lambdaFunction.node.addDependency(deploymentBucket);
  }
}


In the cloudformation console, can you confirm that the lambda only starts deploying after the bucket deployment (not just the bucket) is finished? (you don't need the addDependency btw, since the lambda already depends on deployment.deployedBucket)

Yes, I can confirm that lambda starts only after bucket deployment is complete.

What happens if you add the lambda after the initial stack creation?

Figured out what my issues was. cdk.Fn.select(0, deployment.objectKeys) on code: lambda.Code.fromBucket(deployment.deployedBucket, cdk.Fn.select(0, deployment.objectKeys)) wasn't picking up the zipped files from bucket specified by deployment.deployedBukcet. Instead, it was getting it from the asset bucket.

Interesting - the keys shouldn't change if extract is set to false.
